# помогите с BAT файлом

Tags: bat, windows-7

Помогите написать Батник... для вас это семечки, а я пол дня просижу, не зная команд...

есть два текстовых файла: в одной папке. *там есть и другие файлы*

```
ccc.txt  
newww.txt
```

нужно склеить их содержимое, в новый файл `ссс_new.txt`
при этом избежать накладки последней строки первого с первой строкой второго!
далее: `ccc.txt` - переименовать в `ccc_old.txt`
`ccc_new.txt` - переименовать в `ccc.txt`

сам написал следующее:

```
copy ccc.txt+newww.txt all.xxx  
rename ccc.txt ccc_old.txt  
rename all.xxx ccc.txt
```

в ссс было: 111
в newww было: 222
результат:  222111
всё на одной строке, и порядок не верный....
требуемый результат:

111
222

Comment: *пол дня просижу, не зная команд* Конкатенация текстовых файлов - `copy`. Переименование - `move`. Справка - по ключу `/?`. И лучше изменить порядок действий - копировать `ccc.txt` в `ccc_old.txt`, потом к `ccc.txt` добавить `newww.txt`. Так будет 2 команды, а не 3. *избежать накладки последней строки первого с первой строкой второго*? Совершенно невменяемая фраза. Это же не фотографии, это текст.

Comment: @Akina полагаю что топикстартер имеет в виду ситуацию, когда в конце текстового файла нет перевода каретки и следующий за ним текст встает сразу за ним.

Comment: всё верно, нет \r\n

Comment: дописал ещё инфо в тело вопроса....

Comment: *дописал ещё инфо* Файл `newww.txt` должен остаться нетронутым? или на него плевать?

Comment: должен остаться нетронутым.....

Comment: а как прописать переименование файла, так же в BAT, с присвоением не только имени но и ДАТА_ТЕКУЩЕЕ ВРЕМЯ в скобках ??  
примерный шаблон
newww (2019-12-26__11:25)

Comment: Миша, не наглей :)

Comment: ну пожалуйста... сильная запара ... некогда погружаться... прошу гуру подсказать самые простые вещи....

Comment: а лучше даже... чтобы не дата присваивалась, а чтобы перезапись происходила, если файл с таким именем уже есть... , то Батник не может его перезаписать пока...

Comment: вот это просто строчкой ниже нужно дописать?  
if (File.Exists(outputFile)) n++;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приблизительно так:

```
@echo off
set newline=^& echo.

rem добавляем строку в файл ccc.txt
echo %newline% >> ccc.txt

rem конкатеринуем файлы
type ccc.txt newww.txt > ccc_new.txt

rem переименовываем
ren ccc.txt ccc_old.txt
ren ccc_new.txt ccc.txt
```

Если где-то ошибся немного - извините, давно не брал в руки шашку :)

P.S. Добрый я чего то сегодня...

Comment: Всё отлично! Спасибо!